# Facebook c# windows form: Displaying my facebook pages as a column graph to tell the user which page is the most popular by the number of likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Im trying to display my facebook pages' number of likes as a chart in order for the user to know which of the pages is the most popular. I managed to extract and display my facebook page names data to represent the color on the chart, I cant seem to get the number of likes to appear on the y-axis accordingly. I think its something to do with the conversion of my Json to integer? Any help would be appreciated! I used this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/chart) as a ref for my chart.

```
private void topPageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            try
            {

                chart1.Visible = true;

                FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(myToken.Default.token);

                JSONObject pageData = api.Get("/me/accounts");

                var data = pageData.Dictionary["data"];

                List<JSONObject> pageList = data.Array.ToList<JSONObject>();

                foreach (var page in pageList)
                {
                    string[] seriesArray = { page.Dictionary["name"].String };

                    //pull more page information from the page ID
                    JSONObject pageInfo = api.Get(page.Dictionary["id"].String);

                    //store the number of likes
                    int[] pointsArray = {pageInfo.Dictionary["likes"].String};

                    // Add series.
                    for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // Add series.
                        Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);

                        series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
                    }
                }


                // Set palette.
                this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;

                // Set title.
                this.chart1.Titles.Add("No. of Page likes");


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        try
        {

            chart1.Visible = true;

            FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(myToken.Default.token);

            JSONObject pageData = api.Get("/me/accounts");

            var data = pageData.Dictionary["data"];

            List<JSONObject> pageList = data.Array.ToList<JSONObject>();

            foreach (var page in pageList)
            {
                string[] seriesArray = { page.Dictionary["name"].String };

                //pull more page information from the selected ID
                JSONObject pageInfo = api.Get(page.Dictionary["id"].String);

                //
                //store the number of likes


                // Add series.
                for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Add series.
                    Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);

                    int[] pointsArray = new int[seriesArray.Length];
                    pointsArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(pageInfo.Dictionary["likes"].Integer);
                    series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
                }
            }

            // Set palette.
            //  this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;

            // Set title.
            this.chart1.Titles.Add("No. of Fans"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```